# Schema.org Article Microdata on article page and all links to article

Tags: article, microdata, schema.org

I have article pages marked up with schema.org microdata such as the following (simplified):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <div itemprop="name">My Article Title</div>
    <div>by <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span></div>
    <meta itemprop="url" content="/link/to/my-article" />
    <div itemprop="articleBody">Article body goes here.</div>
</div>
```

I have various pages that link to these article pages, such as archive pages segmented by year and month, tag pages, search results, etc. On all of these pages that have links to articles, should I also add schema.org markup such as this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/link/to/my-article"><span itemprop="name">My Article Title</span></a>
</div>
```

Or is that frowned upon and/or penalized by the search engines?

Answer (score 1):

This is a recommended practice in schema.org, you should a url property in each link to another page containing a specific schema item, *without* any extra information that will be contained on the specific schema item page. e.g. for each link on the collection of articles list:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/link/to/my-article">My Article Title</a>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/link/to/another-article">Another Article Title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think it's frowned upon by search engines at all.  Remember, microdata doesn't **directly** affect your SEO.  Microdata may *indirectly* affect your SEO, to an extent.

The object of microdata is to create "rich snippets" to make your link look nice and "more clickable" in SERPS (search results) so an end-user is more likely to visit your website or article.

So in other words, where a SERP with microdata may look like (without the href code):

```
Rbeezi's Articles Inc.
Welcome to Rbeezi's Articles.  Please read through <a href="link.html" 
itemscope="url">Article # 1</a>.  You may also find it very useful to read through <a 
href="link.html" itemscope="url">Article 2</a> for more information on oceanography.
```

This **rich snippet** is much more professional and user-friendly than just having your title and a bunch of jumbled meta keywords and such (metadata is pretty much obsolete, but you get the idea).  So SEs might bump you up in the SERPS -- it certainly seems to be a trend that will last.  The only con I can think of to using microdata is that maybe an end-user will just click the article link, and if it's to an external website, they won't visit your site.

But in summation, if someone told you 5 years ago that social media was the wave of the future, and you ignored it, you're probably regretting it.  It seems Google and Bing/Yahoo are all on board with schema.org, and that's why I incorporated it into my company's website.  And having said that, I see nothing wrong with your syntax, and I don't think it'll be frowned upon at all by search engines; if anything, it'll be beneficial.

Comment: "The object of microdata is to create "rich snippets" to make your link look nice and "more clickable"" - I wouldn't say it's the _object_ of microdata; that just happens to be what it's currently used for.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it worked great for my sidebar.

```
<ul class="pagination" role="navigation" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPageElement, https://schema.org/ItemList">
                <li class="active" itemprop="additionalType" itemscope="" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement, https://schema.org/itemListElement">
                <a class="more" href="index.php" itemprop="url">
                <span itemprop="name">page 1</span>
                </a>
                </li>
                <li itemprop="additionalType" itemscope="" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement, https://schema.org/itemListElement">
                <a rel="next" class="more" href="page2.php" itemprop="url">
                <span itemprop="name">page 2</span>
                </a>
                </li>
                <li itemprop="additionalType" itemscope="" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement, https://schema.org/itemListElement">
                <a  class="more" href="page3.php" itemprop="url">
                <span itemprop="name">page 3</span>
                </a>
                </li>
                <li itemprop="additionalType" itemscope="" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement, https://schema.org/itemListElement">
                <a class="more next" href="page2.php" itemprop="url">
                <span itemprop="name">page 4</span>
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```